# IOS - Storing Audio and Videos outside App Sandbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am fairly new to IOS App Development. I have an app which plays audio and videos that are present in the App Package. Now I want my app to play audios and videos that are outside the App Package altogether i.e. if I uninstall my app the media files should not be deleted.

I have heard that all the apps can access media files that are added through ITunes. So I want to know the path of this folder(Kindly excuse me if you find my terminology vague. As I said I am fairly new to IOS App Development).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store the files outside app sandbox. Where as we can save image/video files to `photos` app

using, `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`/`UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`

Please check [developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. Can you please elaborate a little.

Also is there a way to store Audio files too in the same way as Video/Images.

Basically what I want is to audios/videos to remain even if I am uninstalling/re-installing the app.

Comment: As @saif says, the only way to save data outside the sandbox is into the device's photo gallery. That means photos and videos only; nothing else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying :)